# Are G-D and Jesus Eternally Co-Equal?

Tags: context

We read in 1 Corinthians 15.28: “And when all things shall be subdued unto him, then shall the Son also himself be subject unto him that put all things under him, that God may be all in all.”

In this text we find the Greek word, ‘hypotassō‘ and the Strong’s concordance defines ‘hypotassō‘ to mean ‘to arrange under,’ ‘to submit to one’s control,’ or ‘to obey.’

If we capitalize the verb [G-D] in this verse, it would read, “And when all things shall be subdued ‘hypotassō‘ unto Him, then shall the Son also himself be subject ‘hypotassō‘ unto Him that put all things under him, that G-D may be all in all.”

G-D is "all knowing" or Omniscient! If Jesus were eternally co-equal with G-D, (or even the Moshiach) then he would know when the Kingdom would be restored to Israel and the House of David!

Cf. Acts 1.6 - 7 (So when they had come together, they were asking Him, saying, “Lord, is it at this time You are restoring the kingdom to Israel?” He said to them, “It is not for you to know times or epochs which the Father has fixed by His own authority; ....) Matthew 24:36 (No one knows about that day or hour, not even the Son, but the Father only.)

Here, in Matthew and in Acts, Jesus makes a distinction between what The FATHER knows and what he, as Lord (Adonee) [not L-RD, Adonai] knows. Clearly, his disciples refer to him as Lord (a Prince - Adonee).

Cf. Acts 3.15 (and killed the Prince of Life...."); Acts 5:31 (Him hath G-D Θεὸς exalted with his right hand to be a Prince Ἀρχηγὸν and a Saviour, for to give repentance to Israel, and forgiveness of sins.)

The authors of Matthew and Acts clearly refer to Jesus as a Lord, (as in 1 Corinthians 15.28 one in subjection 'hypotassō' to G-D, the Father)  rather than as L-RD [Theos] Θεὸς.

Clearly, to Obey implies, submission; something that is the antithesis of Deity!

Moreover, if Jesus became a curse for us, then he could not be Deity for Deity is Blessed; as it is written, "When you have eaten and are satiated, you shall Bless the L-RD your G-D, for the good land which He gave you." Devarim (Deuteronomy) 8.10

As it says, "There is none good but ONE.
John 14:28 "The Father is greater than I."
This is another strong statement that makes a distinction between Jesus and God.

As I read 1 Corinthians 15.28, The Father, (G-D) and Jesus (Adonee Lord) are separate beings, Eternally Un-Equal in this world (Acts 1.6-7) and in the world to come (Matthew 24.36).

Comment: Questions about [Systematic Theology](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/what-constitutes-doctrine/429#429) are typically off topic here. You may wish to ask this at [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) though you will need to ask from a specific doctrinal perspective.

Comment: @James Shewey Permit me to object: the question concerns a specific passage from the Scripture that rises a problem and asks for an exegesis, so I do not see how it does not fit to the Biblical Hermeneutics site.

Comment: I think the question could be better posed.  Your post puts forth a lot of other Scriptures that are loosely connected.  The general question seems to be given various Scriptures, how could one consider Christ to be Divine.

Comment: If you are referring to the traditional Christian faith, then it is coequality as to nature or substance. However, this does not exclude interpersonal obedience, since, according to Scripture, children are to obey their parents, and wives their husbands, despite obviously sharing in the same common humanity.

Comment: As worded this seems like more of an apologetic for your own position than a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

A good question. Just a small note: sorry if I will not share in my answer the abbreviated version of God, or Lord, for I follow a more common international convention, which I think is fine and does not in even a tiny bit diminish the honor of the Addressee.

To answer it, let me first ask, who has resurrected Jesus according to the Gospels? Of course, the Father, for we read: "I was not sent from a man or by a man, but by Jesus Christ, whom the Father raised from dead" (Gal.1:1) (I will not discuss now the first part of this sentence, which clearly puts Jesus above and beyond humanity, and given that Paul elsewhere puts Him above and beyond angels as well (Hebrews 1:4), you may just think, who can be the one who is not to be listed either among humans or among angels, but is over and beyond both?). But let us return to the gist of the matter: we just have seen that Jesus was raised from death by the Father. However, it is also true that He raised Himself, for He says: "No-one takes my life from me, for I have authority to lay down my life, and have authority to take it back" (John 10:18), thus He resurrects Himself, for it is his human body that dies, but the Logos Himself, who adopted the human ensouled body cannot die and is always with Father in Heaven, even after the Incarnation, or better, Inhumanation: (Cf. John 3:13:"No one has ascended to Heaven, except the Son of Man who is in Heaven").

Therefore, it is correct to say both things: a) Father resurrects Jesus and b) Jesus as Logos resurrects His dead body. In fact, to be more precise, the Father resurrects Jesus' dead body through His (Father's) Logos, through the very Logos He created the universe (John 1:3). Not only that. The Father is perfectly impotent to do anything, but through the Logos, His Son, and the divine activity of Both the Father and the Son is thus one activity, for which reason Christ says that He cannot do anything out of Himself (John 5:30), but only what He sees the Father is doing (John 5:19), and it is not that He first sees what the Father is doing and then catches up and repeats it - silly even to suppose that! - but in the eternal dimension of relationship of the Father and the Son there is no hiatus between seeing and doing, and therefore the Son is doing immediately what the Father is "showing" Him, that is to say, Logos is the very means of a l l deeds of the Father, so that the latter is perfectly incapable to perform anything without the Son, just as - to use a famous analogy - a sun is incapable of shedding light without its rays.

And that is the meaning of Jesus metaphorically calling His divine acts "the finger of God" (Luke 11:20), implying that as without touching fingers a doctor is unable to help an ailing patient (in certain types of maladies, e.g. that require surgery), so also the Father is unable to act healing or demon-expelling miracles for humans unless through Jesus. And thus, He says: "My Father has been working until now, and I have been working" (John 5:17), that is to say, Their divine activity is one and they act always together.

Having established this, now we can move to the 1 Cor. 15:28. It deals with the Incarnate or Ihumanate Logos and the saying that the Father is the one who subjects under the Son everything (ὑποτάξαντι /Father/ αὐτῷ /Son/ τὰ πάντα /1 Cor.15:28/), one may ask, if all activity of the Father is conducted through the Logos, as has been established above, then His activity of subjecting all to Christ is also conducted through Logos, Who by virtue of His indispensability and ontological necessity for all actions of the Father is equal to the Father and so eternally.

However, that the "Son will be subjected to the Father, so that God will be all in all, means God's relationship to the humanity of Logos, for indeed the humanity, the created dimension of Christ should be subjected to both Father and Logos, and in Christ Incarnate the entire human nature, all humanity that is under sin and death because of the rebellion and the original fall of Adam and Eve, should be restored to a renewed life and subjected to the obedience of God, just as Christ's human nature is subjected to such an obedience.

Thus, in "God will be all in all" in the second "all" is implied the created universe, while the means by Whom Father will fill all creation with His divine presence is His Logos, for it is impossible for Him to do it otherwise. The most sacred aspect of the creation, its diamond and pinnacle is human heart, and when the Father will fill human hearts or dwell in them eternally, He cannot do so, unless together with the Son, for both dwell equally in human hearts cleansed from sins, and that's why Jesus says: "We will come and make our home with them" (John 14:23), in "We" implying His equality and inseparability from the Father, the equality and inseparability They have for all eternity.